# Why do QGIS users keep telling me that rasters don't have Attribute Tables?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, raster-attribute-table

I'm relatively new to QGIS and am baffled by users telling me that rasters don't have attribute tables. This seems to be at odds with ArcGIS, and what I am able to see in the data I am working with (see screenshot). Someone even made a "Raster Attribute Table" plugin so I know I'm not completely crazy, yet I can't seem to do seemingly simple things like choose what column from the 'RAT' the layer legend is based off of.

Is this just a QGIS quirk or am I using the wrong terminology?

[image: Raster file with AT]

Comment: Probably because QGIS did not support raster attribute tables at until quite recently and those users aren't aware of that.  Note that QGIS raster attribute table support is still very limited compared to ArcGIS.